# What's wrong with my read and write of the file in Android app's assets?

Tags: android, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream, android-assets

Code first:

```
AssetManager mgr = DeviceListActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getAssets();

try {
    Log.e("Glenn:", address);
    FileOutputStream fout = mgr.openFd("device/device_address.txt").createOutputStream();
    PrintWriter _fout = new PrintWriter(fout);
    _fout.println(address);
    Log.e("Glenn", address);

    _fout.close();
    fout.close();

    InputStream fin =  mgr.open("device/device_address.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
    address = br.readLine(); 

    try {
        Log.e("Glenn:", address);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Glenn", "error with OutputStream");
}
```

The value of address printed by the first two `Log.e()` calls is the right value, which actually is a device MAC address.  However, when I was trying to test the value of address read from the file, which had just been written, `NullPointerException` has been caught within the `Log.e()` call. This means the value read from the file is `NULL`. Can anyone point out what's wrong with the code?

Comment: it's possible to write data or change any existing Assets/raw file? i think no not possible because  it is packed(.apk) and not expandable in size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write in your app's asset file. You have only read but not write permissions. [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) only provides methods to read the files from your app's asset folder.

Comment: So how can I save some data for using when re-launch the app? in this case, I wanna save the device's MAC address.

Comment: @user1437534 there are multiple options for persistent storage. See the Docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html